# How to add jquery onclick event to asp radiobutton?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net code:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" CssClass="rb1" GroupName="grp1" runat="server" />
<br/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" CssClass="rb2" GroupName="grp1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the browser it look like this:

```
<span class="rb1">
<input id="MainContent_RadioButton1" type="radio" value="RadioButton1" name="ctl00$MainContent$grp1">
</span>
<br>
<span class="rb2">
<input id="MainContent_RadioButton2" type="radio" value="RadioButton2" name="ctl00$MainContent$grp1">
</span>
<input id="MainContent_TextBox1" type="text" name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBox1">
```

How to add "onclick" event to RadioButton1, so it will clear TextBox1 when clicked?

I'm trying to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("input rb1").click(function () {
        alert('1');
    });
</script>
```

It does nothing.

Comment: Make sure you are including the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mainContent_RadioButton1').click(function() {
```

or

```
$('.rb1 input').click(function() {
```

Comment: Eventually this will be in different application, so "mainContent" will be automatically replaced by something else. Could I use cssClass to add onClick event?

Comment: @user671729 Beware that the handler will be triggered if you use the same css class to a different radio button.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the ClientIDMode attribute to static on the asp checkbox and textbox control and use jquery to register the click event and empty the textbox's value.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" CssClass="rb1" GroupName="grp1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("input#RadioButton1").click(function(){
      $("input#TextBox1").text("");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I put script in the top of asp.net page, so elements was not rendered yet.
It possible to fix by $(document).ready or by putting script in the bottom of the page


`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".rb1 input").change(function () {
            var tb = $("input.tb0");
            tb.val("");
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>`

Comment: My example is a shortcut for document ready, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a `.` the class selector requires a dot like `.rb1`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input .rb1").click(function () {
        alert('1');
    });
</script>
```

after the @SKS pointed out curiously `:p`, `$("input .rb1")` means to look for element(s) with `class=rb1` inside(read children of) the `input` element that doesn't make sense you need to use the selector `$("input.rb1")` like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input.rb1").click(function () {
        alert('1');
    });
</script>
```

that will select the element(s) with `class=rb1`

Comment: I am curious to know what 'input<space>.rb1' means. Btw, the .rb1 is the wrapper around the input.